SATA to USB adapter not working
I bought an AXAGON SDSA-FP3 FASTport3 SATA to USB adapter. I have three HDDs which worked before. Through the adapter sometimes I can write data to them, sometimes they spin up but don't show up in fdisk -l or Double Commander and sometimes they show up but can't be mounted.
rsync on one of the drives ended with
rsync: [receiver] write failed on "/file/on/the/connected/disk": Read-only file system (30)
rsync error: error in file IO (code 11) at receiver.c(378) [receiver=3.2.3]
rsync: [sender] write error: Broken pipe (32)

I started it again, it outputs many of this
rsync: [receiver] mkstemp "/file/on/the/connected/disk.[random 6 characters]" failed: Read-only file system (30)

I use debian. Is the adapter faulty? If not, how can I make it work?

have you tried contacting Axagon tech support

Does adapter have separate power supply or rely on USB port? Some ports have less power, and many HDD require more power. I had an USB adapter that worked well with a SSD, but would not spin up an older HDD.


Through the adapter sometimes I can write data to them, sometimes they spin up but don't show up in fdisk -l or Double Commander and sometimes they show up but can't be mounted.

Sounds like hardware problems, nothing you can solve in software.

rsync: [receiver] mkstemp "/file/on/the/connected/disk.[random 6 characters]" failed: Read-only file system (30)

That very much looks like Linux turned the file system read-only, maybe because it's broken, or because it can't be accessed. The above suggests that it's the latter.
